# ffmpeg: adding blankspace to end of video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to add blankspace to the end of a video (1 audio stream, 1 video stream) using ffmpeg. I'm curious what the best way of doing this is. I'm not very keen on using filter_complex so if there's another simple/viable method, that would be good. I've been trying to use the color filter using the command below, it's making a video with bad timestamps though. On playback it freezes in various parts of the blankspaced segment, my command is missing something.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "color=black:s=1280x720:d=15[b0];[0:v][b0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" output.mkv
```

I receive the green/yellow message below at the point where it starts to render the black frames.

```
[Parsed_color_0 @ 0000000922e0fd900] EOF timestamp not reliable
```

This method is effectively making another video and concatenating it to the first one. I'm wondering if in general: Can you create frames in an existing video...? Or is that outside of how ffmpeg works?

[image]

Comment: @llogan That would be great, pic posted. I also looked up tpad and tried: ffmpeg -i testvid.mkv -vf tpad=start=360:color=0xF0F8FF out.mkv But it said "No such filter: 'tpad'". Guessing I'm doing that one wrong too.

Comment: It's always better to copy and paste the log, since it's text anyway, instead of making a screenshot. It makes answering easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Method 1: [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat)

- **Pros**: Avoids re-encoding the main video and therefore preserves quality since it is [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy). Fast.
- **Cons**: Requires several steps. Harder to get right, because the blank video needs to have the same attributes as the main video.

Make the black video using same attributes and same number and type of streams as the main input. This example makes a 15 second black video, frame rate of 24, size is 1280x720:

```
 ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=24:d=15 black.mkv
```

Make `input.txt`. The order in this text file determines the order that they will appear when concatenating.

```
file 'main.mkv'
file 'black.mkv'
```

Concatenate:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mkv
```

---

## Method 2: [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat)

- **Pro**: Can all be done in one command.
- **Con**: Filtering requires encoding, so no stream copying of the main video as in the concat demuxer. Some attributes must still be matched.

Use the color source filter to make the 15 second, 24 fps, 1280x720 black video and append it to the end of the main video with the concat filter:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mkv -filter_complex "color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=24:d=15[black];[0:v][black]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" output.mkv
```

If you prefer the black to be at the beginning instead then switch the order for the concat filter inputs, such as `[black][0:v]concat…`.

---

## Method 3: [tpad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) and [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) filters

- **Pro**: Easy. No need to match any attributes.
- **Cons**: Filtering requires encoding, so no stream copying of the main video as in the concat demuxer. Relatively new filters: use FFmpeg 4.2 or newer, or even better use a build from the current git master branch.

Append 15 seconds of black video to the end of the main video:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mkv -filter_complex "tpad=stop_duration=15" output.mkv
```

If you want it at the beginning instead use `start_duration` instead of `stop_duration`. If you want to clone the frames instead, or want a different color than black then refer to the [tpad filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad).

Comment: This helps significantly, just 3 issues: (1) Why is there the 'c' in "color=c=black"? Is there a difference vs using "color=black" (seemed the same when tried)? In 14.8 of the docs it lists titles of sections as "color,c" and "duration,d". Doesn't this mean d and duration are interchangeable cmds? Then why does "c=black" give an error? (2) What does 'pad' in "pad video frames" mean? (3) Does ffmpeg not have a way to add frames to an existing video in a 'single' simplified cmd? I was hoping to re-encode like 'method 2', but to create 'new frames', I can't afford to overwrite existing frames.

Comment: @kite 1) It is recommended to include the option name with the value instead of just the value; especially when many other options are being declared. It makes things less ambiguous and you know what you're going to get. `c` is a shortened alias for the `color` option in the color filter. Same with `d` and `duration` as you mentioned. `c=black` gives an error (probably `No such filter: 'c'`) because you are telling it that `c` is the filter name, but there is no filter named `c`. Order is like this: `filterA=option1=value1:option2=value2,filterB=optionB1=valueB1:optionB2=valueB2`.

Comment: @kite 2) "pad" just means to extend, fill, or add. For example, take a 5 second input and extend/fill/add/pad it with black frames at the beginning and/or end to make it 8 seconds. In a way it's similar to `padding` in CSS if you're familiar with that element.
3) Both methods #2 and #3 are single commands, and method #3 is fairly simple. Neither method is overwriting any frames. They are just creating new frames and adding to them the end (and/or beginning if you prefer) of the main input.

Comment: Apologies for my confusion, I misread the video durations and made the wrong assumptions. One final Q: For a movie with [0:0]video+[0:1]audio stream, for method 3 using tpad: adding an "apad=pad_dur=10" worked fine. Of interest though: The docs said you could use -shortest to extend audio streams to the same length as the video stream. Upon trying -filter_complex "tpad=stop_duration=15;apad" -shortest it seems to render an infinitely long video out. I tried writing it like [0:1]apad but no difference either. My intent was to use -shortest to avoid writing out the pad_dur=10 part.

Comment: @kite IIRC, that's a known bug.

Comment: @llogan thank you, your post was the most information I could find about this everywhere! Unfortunately being a complete newb I need some help. 2 Questions;
A) I tried method 1, and the end result was just the non black video, I think I matched the properties, is there a command I can run to check if I did?

Comment: B) I also tried method 3 with success! But I wanted to do a variation but failed. I tried cutting from a file and adding the pad. `ffmpeg -ss 100 -i "input.mp4" -to 32 -vf "tpad=start_duration=10" "output.mp4"`this works, sort of.. It adds 10 seconds at the beginning but doesn't pad it just overwrites the first 10 seconds, and doing it with `stop_duration` doesn't do nothing, the result is only the cut video. What can I do to achieve the result I want?